# Access Calendar Events GData in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I was wondering if anyone knew how to access data from a google calendar in an objective c application. I am trying to create an iPhone application that access the data, process it and display it in a custom format.

I have the sources in the project file and they are compiling fine, but I am having trouble actually getting the data. Can anyone lend me some help. Thanks a lot!

UPDATE:

Alright, I found a simple thing on google's website that gives a brief explanation of stuff, however when I go to use the code provided I get "SIGABRT"

I do believe the error is lying in the didFinishSelector:@selector(ticket:finishedWithFeed:error:).

In method to handle setting everything up.

```
ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                          delegate:self
                 didFinishSelector:@selector(ticket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

The didFinishSelector method is as follows

```
- (void)ticket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
 finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedCalendar *)feed
     error:(NSError *)error {

if (error == nil) {  
    NSArray *entries = [feed entries];
    if ([entries count] > 0) {

        GDataEntryCalendar *firstCalendar = [entries objectAtIndex:0];
        GDataTextConstruct *titleTextConstruct = [firstCalendar title];
        NSString *title = [titleTextConstruct stringValue];

        NSLog(@"first calendar's title: %@", title);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"the user has no calendars");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"fetch error: %@", error);
}

}
```

I get an error every time it tries to access this method. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Alright, I found a simple thing on google's website that gives a brief explanation of stuff, however when I go to use the code provided I get "SIGABRT"

Comment: You will need to single step with the debugger to find the line where it is crashing. The code above looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright someone on another forum helped me out and gave me the following solution and it is working thus far for me. Though I did notice you have to log out of google once you are done editing a calendar or it will not work for some reason.

[Accessing Event Information GDATA](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/80927-accessing-event-information-gdata-api.html#post336973)

What is not stated in that forum is that you will need to declare the following in the interface file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *calendarEvents;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GDataEntryCalendar *googleCalendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CalendarSample application](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample/CalendarSampleWindowController.m) shows how to use the Objective-C library to fetch a user's calendars and calendar entries.

Comment: I have that application already, seeing as it came with the GData Client Library. However, some of the things defined in it are fairly unclear to me. I was hoping someone could give a quick easy example of getting the events from a calendar and simply storing it into a dictionary or array. Once that is completed, I should have no problem doing what I want with it.